# Dll not found exception

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, leap-motion, virtual-reality

I'm new to `Leap Motion`. I'm trying to implement Leap Motion using my mac. But the error shows:

```
DllNotFoundException: LeapC
Leap.ClockCorrelator..ctor ()
Leap.Unity.LeapServiceProvider.Awake () (at Assets/LeapMotion/Scripts/LeapServiceProvider.cs:162)
```

However the `LeapC.dll` is available in `plugins/X86` folder.

Comment: How did you solve this? I found I'm already using the V2 Unity assets from the link @leapmotion_alex offered, but my problem is exactly as you described here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to use the Orion Unity assets with the V2 software (as the Orion tracking software is not available for OSX). The Orion Unity assets are built on the LeapC API, which was introduced in Orion. You need to switch to a Windows machine or revert to the older V2 Unity assets, which can be found here: https://github.com/leapmotion/LeapMotionCoreAssets